# jquery w8n plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been trying to use the jQuery w8n plugin to work. However it doesn't work at all.
I am completely new to plugins I merely just copied what it said to do on the website I got the plug in from, which then didn't work. If anyone is familiar with the plugin I'd appreciate the help.
The website I used was http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Windows-8-Style-jQuery-Notifications-Plugin-w8n.html

```
<head>
<link href="jquery.w8n.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqalert.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="jquery.w8n.js"></script> -->
<script src="jquery.w8n.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {            
        // Sample 1
        $('#btnSample1').click(function(){
          $.w8n('Default notification', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.');
        });                  

      });
    </script>
</head>

<input type="button" id="btnSample1" value="Default"/>
```

Comment: It works fine in the demo .. can you give in the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: I copied the demos code

Comment: still please post the code too .. you might have missed something too

Comment: Define "doesn't work". That's not very explicit.

Comment: When I click the button with id btnSample1, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't looking in the right place for the plugin. Needed the full address in the directory instead of a shorthand version of it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="longversionofwheretofindit"></script>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I solved my own problem so I put it in the comment so it could be solved

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, please provide answer of the problem with explanation and code if possible, to allow users to see necessary information straight away.

Comment: What I said was an answer to the problem, granted not a very detailed one. Didn't realise so many people on here are so awkward. I'll correct it though as may help people in future

Comment: Google is doing a great job on indexing such pages, and stats on search queries proves that there is loads newbies and demand for such knowledge :)